# Ruby on Rails Activerecord - ids are Exchanged in Model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, rails-migrations

I use Ruby in Rails 4.2.0 with Ruby 2.1.0 and I have a self join association. Here is my migration:

```
class CreateStateTemplates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :state_templates do |t|

      t.string :name

      t.references :next
      t.references :prev

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And here is my model:

```
class StateTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :prev, :class_name => "StateTemplate", :foreign_key => "prev_id"
  belongs_to :state_template, :class_name => "StateTemplate", :foreign_key => "prev_id"
  has_one :next, :class_name => "StateTemplate", :foreign_key => "next_id"
  belongs_to :state_template, :class_name => "StateTemplate", :foreign_key => "next_id"

end
```

Here I fill some states:

```
StateTemplate.find(1).update(:next => StateTemplate.find(2))
StateTemplate.find(2).update(:next => StateTemplate.find(3), :prev => StateTemplate.find(1))
StateTemplate.find(3).update(:next => StateTemplate.find(4), :prev => StateTemplate.find(2))
StateTemplate.find(4).update(:next => StateTemplate.find(5), :prev => StateTemplate.find(3))
StateTemplate.find(5).update(:prev => StateTemplate.find(4))
```

But something strange has been happened. When I take one record from StateTemplate and put it on a concole, I've got this:

```
2.1.0 :007 > StateTemplate.find(2)
  StateTemplate Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "state_templates".* FROM "state_templates" WHERE "state_templates"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
 => #<StateTemplate id: 2, name: "two", next_id: 1, prev_id: 3, created_at: "2017-07-22 11:51:30", updated_at: "2017-07-22 11:51:30">
```

Which doesn't right, because `next_id` must be 3, but when I refer to the next state, I've got this:

```
2.1.0 :008 > StateTemplate.find(2).next
  StateTemplate Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "state_templates".* FROM "state_templates" WHERE "state_templates"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  StateTemplate Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "state_templates".* FROM "state_templates" WHERE "state_templates"."next_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["next_id", 2]]
 => #<StateTemplate id: 3, name: "three", next_id: 2, prev_id: 4, created_at: "2017-07-22 11:51:30", updated_at: "2017-07-22 11:51:30">
```

Which is right. And here is my question: why does ids in record is exchanged, but refered to a right record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `belongs_to` associations have the same name (`:state_template`), but they need not have different names. Furthermore I think it is a bit confusing to have `prev` and `next` pointing to `self` instead of pointing to the linked templates.

I would change the associations like this:

```
belongs_to :next, class_name: 'StateTemplate'
belongs_to :prev, class_name: 'StateTemplate'

has_one :predecessor, foreign_key: 'next_id', class_name: 'StateTemplate'
has_one :successor,   foreign_key: 'prev_id', class_name: 'StateTemplate'
```

And this can even be simplified. Because if a template has a `belongs_to :next` than the reverse `has_one` is automatically the `prev`. Therefore remove the `prev_id` from that model and just use the following:

```
belongs_to :next, class_name: 'StateTemplate'
has_one :prev, foreign_key: 'next_id', class_name: 'StateTemplate'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped! But what about this `:predecessor` and `:successor`, is it some options for `belongs_to`?

Comment: Just notice that it can be simplified. Please see my updated answer.